# How to edit the template of link from bootstrap documentation for my needs?

Tags: css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I use template of links from bootstrap documentation, they're blue, I would like a white color.. So how make them all white if links from documntation ingore all my css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

avobe code is from bootstrap. if you want to change this button background or text color. just use this btn-primary class in your css and put your custom code. example

```
.btn-primary {background-color: green; color: red}
```